# How to clear / empty / reset a Relay store?

Tags: relayjs

I am using a relay with react native.

I want to clear Relay store completely when user logs out.

I cannot find the API from this [page](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-store.html#content)

Comment: Release [v0.8.0](https://github.com/facebook/relay/releases/tag/v0.8.0) of Relay introduces `Relay.Environment`, which you can instantiate and pass the instance to `Relay.Renderer`. It's not documented yet. Check out the last few comments of a github issue on this: [Implement RelayStore.reset()](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/233).

Comment: Did you find a way todo this without the environment field?